# Extract a number from a string of numbers and text

Tags: regex, r, text-extraction

I have a data.frame in R with a column containing character string of the form {some letters}-{a number}{a letter}, e.g. `x <- 'KFKGDLDSKFDSKJJFDI-4567W'`. So I want for instance to get a column with the numbers eg '4567' for that particular example/row. Theres only one number but it can be of any reasonable length. How can I extract the number from each row in the data.frame?

Comment: `gsub("[^0-9]+", "", "KFKGDLDSKFDSKJJFDI-4567W")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) to extract substrings. Use `as.numeric` to convert the resulting character string to a number:

```
string = 'KFKGDLDSKFDSKJJFDI-4567W'
as.numeric(regmatches(string, regexpr('\\d+', string)))
# 4567
```

You can easily use this to create a new column in your data frame:

```
#data = data.frame(x = rep(string, 10))
transform(data, y = as.numeric(regmatches(x, regexpr('\\d+', x))))
#                           x    y
# 1  KFKGDLDSKFDSKJJFDI-4567W 4567
# 2  KFKGDLDSKFDSKJJFDI-4567W 4567
# 3  KFKGDLDSKFDSKJJFDI-4567W 4567
# 4  KFKGDLDSKFDSKJJFDI-4567W 4567
…
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
gsub("[a-zA-Z]+-([0-9]+)[a-zA-Z]","\\1", "KFKGDLDSKFDSKJJFDI-4567W")
```